# Issue in the width of a fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

How to make a fixed positioned div fit its content width?

I've made a **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/riless/92s061k3/)**

Before clicking on the **Load** button, the div must only have enough width to contain the gif image and the button.

When more content is loaded, the width of the div must fit its width.

here is the `CSS` I've made

```css
body{background: #eee; }
#divToCenter{
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: its actually fitting the width.it takes padding 20px and the br is taking space

Comment: I'm not talking about that width (padding and br)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using JavaScript/jQuery to show/hide the loader, why don't you change the `width` of the box via JavaScript?

You could simply toggle a class called `.wide` for instance, to achieve the desired result as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/92s061k3/7/)**

**CSS:**

```css
#divToCenter{
    /* other declarations... */
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}

#divToCenter.wide {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```javascript
var $divToCenter = $("#divToCenter");

$("#show-more-data").click(function() {
    // ...
    $divToCenter.addClass("wide");
});

$("#show-less-data").click(function() {
    // ...
    $divToCenter.removeClass("wide");
});
```

Comment: +1 Seems to work as I want, I'll do that if there is no other css-only way to do. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: table`, `position: relative` and `margin:0 auto` to the following element:

```
#divToCenter{
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table;/*Add this*/
    position: relative;/*Change fixed with relative*/
    top: 20px;
    margin:0 auto;/*Add this*/
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/92s061k3/10/)

Comment: the div is not centred anymore

Comment: @Alek relative positioning keeps the element in document normal flow. Considering a popup box, this method is pointless: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/92s061k3/11/

Comment: OP didn't mention anything for pop-up box. If it is pop-up box like modal pop-up etc then probably i suggest another solution. Thx for feedback though :)